# Php file uploaded correctly but not shown correctly in browser

Tags: php, apache, ftp, webserver

I've written my own template, which generates a webpage from several php files. It was working correctly all the time, but since a few days, one file won't show changes in my browser. I've uploaded the file, but in the browser all changes don't appear. I've tried deleting the file and re-upload it, doesn't work. I've tried it in several browsers, all the same... In my localhost, everything works fine!

I've found htcacheclean, but I don't know, how to use it: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htcacheclean.html

If I rename the file, everything works fine, but if I rename It back, things are broken.

Comment: Mabye the cache, have you tried to delete the cache from your browser?

Comment: @C0dekid Yes, I've tried this, but it doesn't work... As written above I've tried it with several browsers, some fresh installed

Comment: @NabinKunwar It's not my own server, I think it's an apache but they said they changed something to nginx for better ssl support

Comment: If it's nginx server I think it's caching the file. can you post the code of accessing that file?

Comment: @NabinKunwar See here: https://leute.server.de/content/beta-test-lets-encrypt-bringt-verschl%C3%BCsselung-f%C3%BCr-alle. They've changed the software for ssl from apache to nginx

Comment: Should clear cache in there.

Comment: @NabinKunwar I use this: `include("footer.php");`. I cannot acces to a Terminal or so, can I clear the servers cache anyway?

Comment: include("footer.php?".time()); IDK will it work. best option is to clear cache from the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107148/discussion-between-linusg-and-nabin-kunwar).